Compare metric to itself of past 1 hour for the past x days?
I want to compare a metric to itself but to the average of the last x days. but the same time range.
example :
current time 14:00
i want to compare todays average for 13:00 - 14:00 for the same range in the past x days.
i know there is an offset function, i can use it for a single day but is there a way for a week or a month?

Does this answer your question? How to calculate average over last week for the same time in prometheus?

Yes, you can and should use offset modifier and it is possible to define
other time durations. i.e for 1 week: avg(http_requests_total[1h] offset 1w)
